# Find participants in a WiFi network in Android app

Tags: android, networking, wifi, bonjour

I want to build a client-server software for use in a WiFi network. On the server I will develop a program which listens on a special port for incomming actions. The client should be an Android app, which should send data to this port. Now I want to find out, which participants are in the WiFi network with their IP adresses for easy usage. I didn't find any functionallity in the Android docs. Is there another solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The best and most portable way to do this is to have your client ask your custom server to tell you about the other clients that have registered with it.

The ability or (more likely) lack of ability to discern this from the network implementation itself is the kind of implementation-specific detail you should generally avoid depending on.

Comment: This would be an solution but the server software can be on every node in a network and the android client doesnt know where!